# How can i get the fields in firestore database which is inside Collection>Documents>Collection>Document?

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

How can I get the fields of my Firestore database? My fields are in a nested way. First is `Collection` > Then `Document` > Then `Collection` >`Document`> Then the **`Fields`**.

````
        dataBabe.collection("categories")
                .document(catId)
                .collection("quesansforquiz")

                .addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onEvent(@Nullable @org.jetbrains.annotations.Nullable QuerySnapshot value, @Nullable @org.jetbrains.annotations.Nullable FirebaseFirestoreException error) {
                        if (!value.isEmpty()) {

                            List<DocumentSnapshot> list = value.getDocuments();
                            questionslist.clear(); //clear old refresh new
                            for (DocumentSnapshot d : list) {         //2:31:04 vid
                                // after getting this list we are passing
                                // that list to our object class.
                                Ques ud = d.toObject(Ques.class);
                                ud.setOp1(d.getId());

                                // and we will pass this object class
                                // inside our arraylist which we have
                                // created for recycler view.
                                questionslist.add(ud);
                            }
                            ptoAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        } else {
                            // if the snapshot is empty we are displaying a toast message.
                            Toast.makeText(getApplication() , "No data found in Database", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                });```



[![pic1][1]][1]
[![pic2][2]][2]
[![pic3][3]][3]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/kdh65.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/nVS2I.png
  [3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hcxbJ.png
````

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To be able to get the field values of one document that exist under the "quesansforquiz" subcollection, you need to know all document IDs that compose the reference ahead of time. So a DocumentReference object that should be used, should look like this:

```
FirebaseFirestore rootRef = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
DocumentReference docRef =  rootRef.collection("categories").document("8I3nyOerWBXyo2i8mz9q")
                                   .collection("quesansforquiz").document("Y5bjDSI9IKIN3iA4c4xa");
```

Then we should attach a listener on the reference and get the corresponding data:

```
docRefd.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {
        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
            DocumentSnapshot document = task.getResult();
            if (document.exists()) {
                Log.d(TAG, document.getString("a"));
            } else {
                Log.d(TAG, "No such document");
            }
        } else {
            Log.d(TAG, "get failed with ", task.getException());
        }
    }
});
```

The result in the logcat will be:

```
pelican
```

P.S. Please check if the value of the document IDs corresponds to the one in your database. I just copied them quickly from your screenshots. In the same way, I got the value of "a", you can get the others, using `document.getString("i")`, `document.getString("op1")` and so on.

**Edit:**

According to your last comment:

> Yes, I want all documents.

To get all documents that exist under the "quesansforquiz" sub-collection, please use the following lines of code:

```
FirebaseFirestore rootRef = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
DocumentReference collRef =  rootRef.collection("categories").document("8I3nyOerWBXyo2i8mz9q")
                                   .collection("quesansforquiz");
collRef.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
            for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                Ques ques = document.toObject(Ques.class);
                Log.d(TAG, ques.a);
            }
        } else {
            Log.d(TAG, "Error getting documents: ", task.getException());
        }
    }
});
```

The result in the logcat will be:

```
pelican
///Other restuls
```

Comment: The problem is that its a dynamic quiz app ..and For the first document i can get the id by AdapterClass (which the user selects givees the first document id( i am passing the first Doc ID using PutExtra here)) ..Problem is that how can i get 2nd doc id and the fields...... Without using .collection("quesansforquiz").document("Y5bjDSI9IKIN3iA4c4xa"); in the last

Comment: Do you need to get a single document, as in my answer, or all documents within the `quesansforquiz` suncollection?

Comment: Check my new answer in bottom..yes i want all documents

Comment: please see my new added answer below the original answer.... In this method i am getting the questions and options..but dont know how instead of 5 questions ..i am getting 7...(last 2 are repeat of question 5)

Comment: If you need all documents, please see my updated answer. Give it a try and tell me if it wroks.

Comment: Hey Kumar. Have you tried my updated solution?

Comment: Yes your method is working ...But can you say me why i my method i am getting 7 questions. and aswnwers... Till 5 questions all are ok..but 6th and 7th  question and option are repeat of 5th question.

Comment: Didn't debug your code, but most likely it's about that limitation. But good to hear that you made it work :)