# How can i get random fields out of documents from firestore database?

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

[image: This is my database]I am making an online quiz app in which there are 4 options in which random users play the quiz at the same time. I want that the 4 options, option1, option2, option3, option4 should come randomly. Like one user should get Option4 first than option1, O2, O3, 04. Other users shall get say  4,3,1,2,... similarly others can get 3142.

I know that ,
`Random random=new Random();`
`final int rand=random.nextInt(4);`

will generate any random number under 4. But where should I put this to get the desired result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I already explained in the following answer how to get the documents within the "quesansforquiz" sub-collection:

- [How can i get the fields in firestore database which is inside Collection>Documents>Collection>Document?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69087937/how-can-i-get-the-fields-in-firestore-database-which-is-inside-collectiondocume)

Now, to have a random order, you can add all the answers into a List and then shuffle them as bellow:

```
List<String> answers = new ArrayList<>();
answers.add(document.getString("op1"));
answers.add(document.getString("op2"));
answers.add(document.getString("op3"));
answers.add(document.getString("op4"));
Collections.shuffle(answers);

for (String answer : answers) {
        Log.d("TAG", answer);
}
```

In this way, you'll always have a random order of your answers.